# How to make http request using Electron's Node server with Angular 9. net.request({}) cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, electron

I'm trying to create an http GET request to an external server via my Angular Electron app. Due to the CORS policy, I can't use Angular's HttpClientModule and have to resort to using Electron's built in node server (right?).

So after looking at Electron's docs here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/net and here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request, I should be able to utilize the `net.request` functionality, however I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code I'm trying to execute, but I'm getting `Cannot read property request of undefined`, probably due to how `net` is being initialized (or not being initialized):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { net } from 'electron'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  checkUserStatus(authUser) {
    const request = net.request({
      method: 'GET',
      protocol: 'https:',
      hostname: 'github.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/'
    })
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to Electron. Is there something I'm missing or something I can do differently?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I resolved it by setting `webSecurity`  to false in my `index.js`

```
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      ...
      webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
    });
```

you can read about it  [here](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/)

This should be considered as a temporary workaround, the best solution would be to handle the CORS problem on the server-side.

Personally I'd avoid using Node's `net` when it is possible to use `HttpClientModule`.
having said that, here's  how to import electron specific components in the Angular part of the application

```
import * as electron from "electron";
..

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
net = electron.remote.require("net");
..
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Would this be considered a bad practice in production? Or is this pretty much the only work around?

Comment: @StevieStar yes that would be considered as one.

Comment: So then should this not be used in production? I think there's a way to use the Node server in Electron but I'm not sure how to get that working with Angular

Comment: I'm not  aware of your project specifics, but I have suggested a way to import  the electron net, i have tried it in my electron angular project and it seems to be working